# Only one side of join table being saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, many-to-many

In my app, User objects can follow each other, and be followed. The two relationships are distinct.

I'm seeing that when I set `user_a.follows << user_b` that `user_b.followed_by.count` still == 0. Why?

When I play in the console, I see:

```
$ jordan = User.new(:name=>"Jordan")
 => #<User id: nil, name: "Jordan"> 
$ matt = User.new(:name=>"Matt")
 => #<User id: nil, name: "Matt"> 
$ matt.followers << jordan
 => [#<User id: nil, name: "Jordan">] 
$ matt.followers.first
 => #<User id: nil, name: "Jordan"> 
$ jordan.friends.first
 => nil 
$ matt.save

  SQL (14.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name") VALUES (?)  [["name", "Matt"]] 
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name") VALUES (?)  [["name", "Jordan"]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "followings" ("followee_id", "follower_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["followee_id", nil], ["follower_id", 2]]
 => true
```

My objects are defined as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :follower_followee_rel,  
            :class_name         => "Following",
            :foreign_key        => 'followee_id',
            :dependent          => :destroy
  has_many  :friends, 
            :through            => :follower_followee_rel, 
            :source             => :followee
  has_many  :followee_follower_rel,           
            :class_name         => 'Following',
            :foreign_key        => 'follower_id',
            :dependent          => :destroy
  has_many  :followers, 
            :through            => :followee_follower_rel, 
            :source             => :follower
end

class Following < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :followee, 
              :class_name         => 'User'
  belongs_to  :follower, 
              :class_name         => 'User'
end
```

Totally ignoring the second half of the relationship.

No errors are raised. What's going on?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use the `has_many:through` relationship? It may just be me, but I find your `User` model definition confusing. *Edit* Oh, because of the potential non-symmetry? *Edit* I'm confused, like I said.

Comment: The relationship does use `has_many :through`. `has_many :friends, :through=>:follower_followee_rel`.

Comment: Like I said, I find the `User` model declaration confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join relationships don't work unless the two models that are being joined have both already been saved. You can see on the 3rd line of the SQL that nil is being inserted for followee_id, as jordan doesn't yet have an id.

You would also need to save matt before you check jordan's friends, because doing `matt.followers << jordan` is treated as a modification of matt that doesn't effect anything else until matt is saved.

Comment: This was definitely a prerequisite. I also found that I had the foreign keys reversed, which confused active record.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing [Michael Fairley's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460274/only-one-side-of-join-table-being-saved/7463729#7463729) got ActiveRecord to build the relationship, but the relationship was still being defined wrong.

Final solution was to save the records in advance of joining them, and to fix the foreign keys, which were backwards.

Was:

```
has_many  :follower_followee_rel,  
          :class_name         => 'Following',
          :foreign_key        => 'followee_id',
          :dependent          => :destroy

has_many  :friends, 
          :through            => :follower_followee_rel, 
          :source             => :followee

has_many  :followee_follower_rel,           
          :class_name         => 'Following',
          :foreign_key        => 'follower_id',
          :dependent          => :destroy

has_many  :followers, 
          :through            => :followee_follower_rel, 
          :source             => :follower
```

Is now:

```
has_many  :follower_followee_rel,  
          :class_name         => 'Following',
          :foreign_key        => 'follower_id',
          :dependent          => :destroy

has_many  :friends, 
          :through            => :follower_followee_rel, 
          :source             => :followee

has_many  :followee_follower_rel,           
          :class_name         => 'Following',
          :foreign_key        => 'followee_id',
          :dependent          => :destroy

has_many  :followers, 
          :through            => :followee_follower_rel, 
          :source             => :follower
```

Change is found @

`:follower_followee_rel, :foreign_key=>'followee_id'`
and
`:followee_follower_rel, :foreign_key=>'followee_id'`